# keep original new lines in mysql text field

Tags: html, mysql

I have this in notepad++

```
<p>line 01</p>

<p>line 02</p>
```

Copy from notepad++ and Paste into mysql table - text field - no problem

I'm using phpMyAdmin

Now copying this from the table and paste into notepad++ I have this:

```
<p>line 01</p>  <p>line 02</p>
```

So, entire text is in one block.
How can I prevent this?

I need new lines as it was in original (for later editing purpose).

Comment: What tool are you using for inserting or retrieving? The problem is likely there.

Comment: MySQL preserves end of line, so the problem is either notepad++ or the mysql client your are using or the way your are copy/pasting. This is definitely not a code question.

Comment: @tadman, I'm using phpMyAdmin, and standard Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Maybe phpMyAdmin is eating the newlines. It's not necessarily the most sophisticated of tools. Try [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) which is also free but *significantly* better.

Comment: @bonaca Which mysql client are you using to read/display the data? When it is php you can use the `nl2br()` function.